# Ruby on Rails - Creating report grouped

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a db table="records" with customer names and what they have purchased as follows:

```
Name, price, item
Sam, 10USD, fruits
John 12USD, toy
Alice 8USD, icecream 
Sam, 20USD, fruits
Sam, 17USD, meat
Alice, 14USD, icecream 
John, 45USD, toy
Alice, 60USD, tie
John, 14, sandwich
Alice, 5USD, icecream
John, 60, tie
```

I would like to create a simple report table showing each customer's average spending, total spendings and frequent buying item.

```
Name    Ave Total   Favorite
Alice   21.75   87   icecream 
John    32.75   131  toy
Sam 15.66   47   fruits
```

I couldn't figured out how I can group records and make calculations in the model. I will appreciate if you can guide me how I can achieve it.

I need help on the model function(s) to prepare variables for my view templates

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far.

Comment: I tried to calculate total spendings like this but get an error:  total_spendings = Record.sum(:price, :group =>:name)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Comment: Did you try `Record.group(:name).sum(:price)`

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will appreciate if you can share link with me from where I can get more info about groupings (suitable for a beginner please :) )

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum